# Load images to the stage dynamically using textfile in Action Script 3

Tags: actionscript-3

I would like to add an image to the flash stage dynamically using a textfile. Using the URLLoader and URLRequest classes to access the textfile named textPic.txt. Currently I have loaded the textfile using this script:

```
public class imgLoader extends MovieClip
    {
        private var myTextloader:URLLoader=new URLLoader();
        var fl_TextURLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("textPic.txt");


        public function imgLoader()
        {
            myTextloader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onloaded);
            //myTextloader.load(new URLLoader("textPic.txt"));
            myTextloader.load(fl_TextURLRequest);
        }
            private function onloaded(e:Event):void
        {
            trace(e.target.data);

        }
```

Comment: Although it is feasible to use a text file as a data holder, xml is the preferred way to do this, there are many tutorials on loading xml and using it for referencing images. - here's one for example http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3gridgallery/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;

var ldr :URLLoader = new URLLoader;
ldr.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, loadHandler );
ldr.load( new URLRequest('images.json') );

function loadHandler( e:Event ):void
{
    var rawData:String = String(e.target.data);
    var imageData:Array = JSON.decode(rawData) as Array;

    for (var i:int = 0; i < imageData.length; i++)
    {
       trace( imageData[i].name + '  url: ' + imageData[i].url );
    }
}
```

images.json:

```
[
  {
     "name": "Image 1",
     "url": "image1.jpg"
  },
  {
     "name": "Image 2",
     "url": "image2.jpg"
  },
  {
     "name": "Image 3",
     "url": "image3.jpg"
  }
]
```